# Json input to Sql table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, open-json

I've a requirement to load the json input into a table which has multiple arrays

```
declare @json nvarchar(max);

set @json =
'{

            "method":"email",
            "value":"xxx@gmail.com",
            "options":[
            {
                "type":"Regular",
                "alerts":true,
                "subsciptions":true
            },
            {
                "type":"service",
                "alerts":false,
                "subsciptions":false
            }
            ]
            
            
}'
```

So i wrote the below query to achieve that

```
SELECT  a.Method,value

            FROM
            OPENJSON(@json)
            WITH
            (
             method varchar(10) N'$.method'
            ,value varchar(100) N'$.value'
            ,options NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
        ) AS a
        CROSS APPLY
        OPENJSON(a.options)
        WITH
        (
            type varchar(100) N'$.type'
            ,alerts INT N'$.alerts'
            ,subscription varchar(10) N'$.subscription'
        ) AS b;
```

So, I'm getting the output as expected

```
method, value, type, alerts, subscription

email, xxx@gmail.com, Regular, true, true

email, xxx@gmail.com, service, true, true
```

Now the requirement has been changed regarding the multiple arrays, so sometimes the options array is available and sometimes they are not available,

I'm trying to write a query which can work for both the logics,
so when there is no options array, the output should be like,

```
method, value, type, alerts, subscription

email, xxx@gmail.com, NULL, NULL, NULL

email, xxx@gmail.com, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

and when the options array is available, the output should be like,

```
method, value, type, alerts, subscription

email, xxx@gmail.com, Regular, true, true

email, xxx@gmail.com, service, true, true
```

Could you please help me write a query to achieve this logic

Comment: If you replace `CROSS APPLY` with `OUTER APPLY`, will result be better?

Comment: Maybe you simply need to replace `CROSS APPLY` with `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time Arvo and Zhorov...It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Using your demo variable:

```
SELECT a.[Key], CASE WHEN ISJSON(a.value) = 0 THEN a.value END AS value, b.[Key] AS ArrayKey, c.[Key] AS ArraySubKey, c.Value AS ArraySubValue
 FROM OPENJSON(@json) a
   OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(CASE WHEN ISJSON(a.value) = 1 THEN a.Value END) b
   OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(b.value) c
```

This produces a table which shows all of the values, with their respective sub keys and values. `OUTER APPLY` is used because not all values will have sub values. I also used a `CASE` expression to only attempt to parse the sub values where they are valid JSON.

| Key | value | ArrayKey | ArraySubKey | ArraySubValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| method | email | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| value | xxx@gmail.com | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| options | NULL | 0 | type | Regular |
| options | NULL | 0 | alerts | true |
| options | NULL | 0 | subsciptions | true |
| options | NULL | 1 | type | service |
| options | NULL | 1 | alerts | false |
| options | NULL | 1 | subsciptions | false |